# How-to: Woocommerce dont send email after order status set to Completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i’m using woocommerce with 2 types of production variation. Variation A is a virtual downloadable product, when ordered is placed woocommerce sends the  “order completed” template email, order is marked automatically as Completed. Variation B is a downloadable product and includes shipping a physical product, order is placed, customer gets 1st email “order is being processed” then I update the order with the tracking code, and a “customer note” template is sent saying order has been shipped. And that’s it. All working goos. The problem is that for the sake of having all orders organized on the backoffice, i would like to sent the shipped orders to “completed” , but when I do that an email is sent the “order completed” (just like when customer orders a virtual product) . What I would like to know is how can I stop this last email, “completed order”, for being sent without compromising the customers that buy virtual products?

I have tried on woocommerce / emails / completed order / uncheck notifications . But when i do that customers who buy a virtual product dont get any email.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to find an appropriate hook in the place where those emails actually get send, and than in your callback function you will have to check what kind of product(s) the order actually contained - and based on that, either let it continue sending the email, or break it off at that point.

Comment: Thanks. Ok that seems the way. I’ve been searching for another alternative, creating a custom order  status, eg: Shipped, and select that state when order is shipped.